# The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk.login error 301.)

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-login, fbsdk

When I clicked on loginWithFacebook button, I'm getting this error,

> The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk.login error 301.)

There is no much information regarding what is this error code 301 means. Any suggestions or info regrading this greatly appreciated.

Note: This one is not getting in iPhone, specifically when I run on iPAD. Don't know why.

Comment: where u get error ? please elaborate ...

Comment: When Clicking on loginWithFacebook button

Comment: which language swift or ObjC?

Comment: Swift. Getting error in this method: facebookLogin.logIn(withReadPermissions: [EMAIL, PUBLIC_PROFILE], from: self, handler: { (facebookResult, facebookError)

Comment: Please give code on your que

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got to know what causes this error. Even though it's funny error, it's good to know about this. The device which I'm running on has no browser to use. So facebook wants to open url in browser and it's failed to do so. That gave me error with **facebookSDK.Login.Error.code: 301.**

You can resolve this by setting **FBSDKLoginManager.loginBehaviour** to required behaviour(Browser, Web or App).

Comment: i am receiving same error on iPhone 7 plus IOS 15 . I am trying Facebook login. it is working perfectly on android. but throwing error on iOS.
Would you please explain how to implement above solution.

Answer (score 0):

**This is my code working properly**

Please import first

```
  import FacebookLogin
  import FBSDKLoginKit 

func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!) {

if(FBSDKAccessToken.current() != nil)
    {
        //print permissions, such as public_profile
        print(FBSDKAccessToken.current().permissions)
        let graphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields" : "id, name, email"])
        let connection = FBSDKGraphRequestConnection()

        connection.add(graphRequest, completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in

            let data = result as! [String : AnyObject]

            self.lbluser.text = data["name"] as? String

            let FBid = data["id"] as? String
            self.lblEmail.text = data["email"] as? String

            let url = NSURL(string: "https://graph.facebook.com/\(FBid!)/picture?type=large&return_ssl_resources=1")
            self.imageView.image = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOf: url! as URL)! as Data)
        })
        connection.start()
    }
}
```